# Android - Firebase App Indexing App not showing in google autocomplete suggestions

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-indexing

I am trying to implement Firebase App Indexing, while the task to update the *indexable* is showing success and the index is also shown in the *In Apps* tab after searching in Google App. From what I understand, the index should also show up in the Auto Complete Suggestions when searching in the Google App but its not shown. I am following the tutorial from [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/app-indexing/index.html#0). Following is the code snippet I am using to index the content:

```
Indexable menuItemToIndex = Indexables.noteDigitalDocumentBuilder()
                            .setName(title)
                            .setText(text)
                            .setUrl(link)
                            .build();

Task<Void> task = FirebaseAppIndex.getInstance().update(menuItemToIndex);

task.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        Log.d(TAG, "App index updated: " + title);
    }
});
```

Also the version of the Firebase App Indexing library I'm using is

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.1'
```

Is there anything I'm missing?
I am testing on Nexus 6P running on Stock `7.1.1` and Google App version `6.9.36.21.arm64`.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I have followed the tutorial step by step and the suggestions do not appear. I have checked the Firebase App Indexing DB within the Google developer tools and my items are there, but for some reason the Google app does not show them.

Comment: Can you check the intent handler for the URL is set up properly in your app? What scheme are you using for the links?

Comment: make sure the deep links are in proper format. The URI format for deep link is  -  android-app://<package_name>/<scheme>/<host_path>.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I also run into this problem. First be absolutely sure you see the firebase logging (see https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/app-indexing/#12)  
If you see that then check if you have enough disk space available for indexing. Wasn't showing up in the logs at all in my case. just like you results in the google app. I tried it on a different phone and it worked instantly.

Answer (score 3):

[Indexables](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/appindexing/builders/Indexables) need to be built with the [Indexable.Builder](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/appindexing/builders/IndexableBuilder), per item (which hints for a loop) ...while the [DigitalDocumentBuilder](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/appindexing/builders/DigitalDocumentBuilder) is a rather specific implementation of it, especially for digital documents.

```
Indexable recipe = new Indexable.Builder()
    .setName("Brownie Recipe")
    .setUrl("//acme.com/recipes/12345678")
    .build();

FirebaseAppIndex.getInstance().update(recipe);
```

- check out the [AppIndex](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/appindexing/FirebaseAppIndex) documentation or
- build and run the AppIndexing [Quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android):

  `git clone https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android.git`.
- further reading: [Enabling Deep Links for App Content](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html).

the tutorial (and the question) appears a little dated; the current version is `11.0.2`.

also `com.google.android.gms`:`play-services-appindexing` is required.

Comment: `appears a little dated`. Good joke. What's the point of touching rusted questions? 3 years is hell lot of time in IT

Comment: well, it was on top of the stack and not yet answered - and so I've  explained it. have no clue by which parameters these are being sorted, often seen questions which received "too little attention". and with 31 up-votes and 4 users following it, it still makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

After updating items like you have done, you also need to create a corresponding view action with the same url you used to update the item, just like in the recipe app, before it will appear in auto complete.

```
FirebaseUserActions.getInstance().start(Actions.newView(item.getTitle(),"http://example.com/item?id=5"))
```